# Populate missing data based on two pre-existing factors

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
a <- c(1:9)
b <- as.factor(c("Day", "Day", NA, "Night", NA, "Day", NA, "Night", "Night"))
df<-data.frame(a=a,b=b)
```

I would like to conditionally replace the NA values, based on the values that already exist, in order to create this:

```
df$a <- c(1:9)
df$b <- as.factor("Day", "Day", "Dusk", "Night", "Dawn", "Day", "Dusk", "Night", "Night")
```

I've explored using na.locf() and fill() but haven't quite managed to figure out a solution yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
require(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(b=as.factor(case_when(is.na(b) & lag(b)=="Day" ~ "Dusk",
                 is.na(b) & lag(b)=="Night" ~"Dawn",
                 TRUE ~ as.character(b))))

  a     b
1 1   Day
2 2   Day
3 3  Dusk
4 4 Night
5 5  Dawn
6 6   Day
7 7  Dusk
8 8 Night
9 9 Night
```

This approach uses `dplyr` to mutate `b` and change any NA that follows "Day" to "Dusk" and any NA that follows "Night" to "Dawn", leaving anything else as it is (including any leading NAs, if there were any).

Comment: Thank you for this! Is there a solution for if there are multiple NAs next to each other? I also do have leading NAs in my dataframe, so a solution that deals with this would also be great!

Comment: I've then used na.locf() to deal with multiple NA values - filling in these NAs with the previous non-NA value.

Comment: Well, that depends on how you want to fill those. Do you have a consistent logic to where the same word should appear twice in a row?